How to allow chrome to open local files?
I have a trusted site some-domain.com, how can I tell Chrome to let open local links like file:///reports/2022-06-12.pdf from that site?
By default it's not possible, Chrome show error Not allowed to load local resource: file:///reports/2022-06-12.pdf

you can't.
refer this this to understand how runtime environments work.
